# Understanding avconv console output

Tags: linux, video, raspberry-pi, libav

I'm using avconv to broadcast a video on justin.tv from my Raspberry Pi.

I get it (weakly) working a very few times. Most of the times justin.tv is not being updated and says "disconnected".

The command is:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640×360 -r 10 -b 350k -i /dev/video0 \
-f flv rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/live_520myKey
```

After transmitting a few frames my console keeps printing:

```
frame=    3 fps=0 q=2.0 Lsize=79kB time=8043.93 bitrate=0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 
frame=    3 fps=0 q=2.0 Lsize=79kB time=8043.93 bitrate=0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2
.......
frame=    3 fps=0 q=2.0 Lsize=79kB time=8043.93 bitrate=0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=4000
```

Frame number does not change but drop keeps increasing.

Does this mean:

1. The video stream is not created/crashed (by some webcam/system)
   fault?
2. The video stream is not transmitted due to some problem with
   my internet dongle (e220)?

What I understand is frame number 3 was not transmitted and avconv is trying to transmit it repeatedly. Some times this is 3...some times 6...10 like that and it stops there and just repeats increasing the `drop=xx` number.

Can you please tell me what's happening here?

Comment: Please include the command and its full, uncut output.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to get the command output to a log file.. command > log.log didn't work..maybe because I CTRL+C to exit..
The command is 
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640×360 -r 10 -b 350k -i /dev/video0 -f flv rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/live_520myKey

Comment: `avconv … 2> /path/to/log` should suffice. Please [edit] your question with the info. Thanks

Comment: it didn't work because I always have to CTRL+C from the command to stop streaming... pls see my edited comment above...